# Бекап DC для восстановления на другом железе

Tags: active-directory, контроллер-домена, windows-server-2012

В сети только один контроллер домена на Windows Server 2012 r2. Как правильно делать его бекап чтобы потом была возможность восстановить его уже на другом железе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поднять BDC на другом железе, сделать репликацию PDC c BDC ну и поднять BDC до уровня PDC.

Comment: Собственно, BDC для того и должен быть!

Comment: поддержу такое решение